# Orbeon PDF with custom CSS

Tags: pdf, orbeon

I would like to show checkboxes and radiobuttons horizontal and not vertical (sidenote: are there plans to add this align option via property setting in the control itself? ). To do this I created an extra CSS file which works in the html version of the form.

It used to work in PDF with 4.3 but with the upgrade to 4.6.2 this isn't the case any more.

For test I created a @media print section which hides the labels. When changing the media type in Chrome to print the section gets executed and the whole checkbox gets hidden.
When creating the PDF the label gets hidden but the checkboxes stay visible (same with the alignment; they always stay vertical).

By the looks of it I have the right CSS selector (works in html and partial in PDF) but what's with the radio and checkbox? They don't take into account the changes I made.

Comment: Does your CSS work in view mode? The PDF renderer has a CSS processor which is different from the browser's, and it can be tricky to figure out. Did you check [these guidelines](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Styling-automatic-PDFs)?

Comment: Yes I did read the guide. Did you change the CSS processor between 4.3 and 4.6? If so maybe their website could help me with this.

Comment: No it's the same. But there were changes to the CSS in view and PDF modes, see: http://blog.orbeon.com/2014/03/review-and-pdf-improvements.html. We dont' use native checkboxes anymore in these cases, but overlay images.

Comment: Guess this is the issue then. Print shows the images, screen shows the native browser checkboxes. Can I change this with the right CSS  tags or does Orbeon do something in the backend to get this images into the PDF?

Comment: In "view" mode the browser should show the images too. Do you mean can you get the PDF to show native checkboxes? Our conclusion is that it is hopeless to get the PDF renderer to do that properly. So we use images instead. But your initial questions was about vertical vs. horizontal. That should be achievable.

Comment: View mode shows the browser native checkboxes. PDF view shows the images of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwrote the whole css selector:

```
.orbeon .fr-mode-view .xforms-select-appearance-full.xforms-static .xforms-selected   ,
.orbeon .fr-mode-pdf .xforms-select-appearance-full.xforms-static .xforms-selected  ,
.orbeon .fr-mode-email .xforms-select-appearance-full.xforms-static .xforms-selected  ,
.orbeon .fr-mode-view .xforms-select1-appearance-full.xforms-static .xforms-selected  ,
.orbeon .fr-mode-pdf .xforms-select1-appearance-full.xforms-static .xforms-selected  ,
.orbeon .fr-mode-email .xforms-select1-appearance-full.xforms-static .xforms-selected  ,
.orbeon .fr-mode-view .xforms-input.xforms-type-boolean.xforms-static .xforms-selected  ,
.orbeon .fr-mode-pdf .xforms-input.xforms-type-boolean.xforms-static .xforms-selected  ,
.orbeon .fr-mode-email .xforms-input.xforms-type-boolean.xforms-static .xforms-selected  {
    background-image: url("images/glyphicons/checkbox-selected-hd.png");
    display: inline-block;  white-space: nowrap;
}
```